# Why does my ASP.NET Core MVC application add some identifier to HTML elements?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

When running my new ASP.NET Core MVC application and viewing it in the browser, it seems ASP.NET Core added some kind of ID to some HTML elements.

I'm using .NET 6, and Razor `.cshtml` pages.

Why? And how to disable this?

[image: Some kind of ID is added]

Comment: Have you checked if those attributes are coming from the server? Maybe you have some JavaScript that could do so? You can check what html is coming from the server in the Network tab in the DevTools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from [Blazor CSS Isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

You can disable it by adding `<ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>` to your app's project file (.csproj).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#disable-css-isolation